# Device tree address and reg and property

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I'm struggling to understand where to get the address of a device on a device tree? As an example how do I know that I should set `<0x00900000 0x20000>` in [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl.dtsi#L65).

Is memory mapped IO done in the hardware (the processor itself) or in software and do I just have to pass the right address in the device tree?

Is the address hardcoded on the processor or can I just set an arbitrary address? I cannot find anything in my reference manual about setting a certain address in the device tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kind of addresses can be found in the Reference Manual of the processor.

You can find the [link here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/IMX6SDLRM.pdf).

Take a look at the chapter 48 (OCRAM On-chip RAM Memory Controller) and more specifically at the section 48.2.1  (page 4118):

> The total on-chip RAM size for the chip is 128 Kbytes, organized as 16K x 64 bits,mapped from 0x00900000 to 0x0091FFFF

This is where come from the values `<0x00900000 0x20000>` from the dtsi file, corresponding to the base address and the offset.

These values are in dts/dtsi file provided by the chip maker.